# Is it possible to parse Queries in MongoDB to get more specific results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, database, nosql

I want to get time greater than 2:00 and less than 8:00 in my mongoDb. However, my data looks like this:

{"time": "4:35"}

The colon prevents me from making queries like "db.collection.find( { time: { $gt: 2, $lt: 8 } } )" Is there some way to query this? (Perhaps parse 4:35 into 435 without changing the inner data)

Comment: You could have relied on string sorting if the time had been stored as `04:35`, then you could have done `02:00` and `08:00`. Unfortunately, the best choice would be to fix the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you just wanted to search for the time between 2 and 8 then you could probably try this:

```
db.collection.find( { time: { $gt: "2:00", $lt: "8:00" } } )
```

This is what i have done to test this. I have inserted few data to the collections and here is the the list:

> db.time.find({},{"_id":0})
>   { "mytime" : "4:35" }
>   { "mytime" : "1:35" }
>   { "mytime" : "6:35" }
>   { "mytime" : "8:35" }
>   { "mytime" : "10:35" }
>   { "mytime" : "10:10" }
>
> > db.time.find( { mytime: { $gt: "2:00", $lt: "8:00" } }, {"_id":0} )
> >     { "mytime" : "4:35" }
> >     { "mytime" : "6:35" }

Comment: 10 would be less than 8 with string sorting in this way

Comment: That unfortunately doesn't work :( the value in the db is not a number. It's a string that looks like this -> "4:35"

Comment: This is helpful. I did a smaller scale test and it actually does work! There is a small problem though. If you insert "21:34", this value gets returned too. I believe the reason why is because the first digit is in the range. This is the next thing i'm trying to figure out. Thanks a bunch

Comment: if you give the hours as full hours as 2:00, you should be able to filter 21:34 `db.time.find( { "mytime": { $gt: "2:00", $lt: "8:00" } }, {"_id":0} )`

Answer (score 0):

Storing times as strings is a bad idea. Unfortunately MongoDB has no dedicated time-only data type, but there are two alternatives which are not as bad as using strings:

1. use a BSON Date. When storing the year, month and day would be counter-productive, set all these to the same value (the start of the epoch, Jan 1st 1970, would be an option).
2. use an integer, and have it represent the number of minutes or seconds since midnight. Do the conversion on the application-layer.